# How do used Python selenium xpath get website information, Get the six continents, ranked of country population put the numbers in descending order

Tags: python, list, selenium, dictionary, xpath

Website: https://www.ifreesite.com/population

### Get the six continents, ranked  of country population put the numbers in descending order.

## Expected output:

非洲 AFRICA

[1.]["Burundi","蒲隆地 / 布隆迪","11,178,921"]

[2.]["Djibouti","吉布地 / 吉布提","887,861"]

[3.]["Comoros","葛摩 / 科摩羅","788,474"]

、

、

、

亞洲 ASIA

[1.]["China ","中國","1,427,647,786"]

[2.]["Japan","日本","126,573,481"]

[3.]["Republic of Korea","南韓","50,293,439"]

、

、

、

Next step. how can i do, im student learening Python  need help. Thanks.

Code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
        
driver_path = r'C:\Users\leon_shih\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\chromedriver.exe'
        
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path)
        
driver.get("https://www.ifreesite.com/population/")
        
time.sleep(3)
        
for result0 in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class ="if_table starj taggllj"]'):
    print(result0.text)
for result1 in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr/td/div/span[@class ="stare"]'):
    print(result1.text)
for result2
```

need get website information:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kETmm.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWp1E.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHs0V.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ER61.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfrhb.jpg)

Comment: what is you expected output?

Comment: Did you try out anything by now? Code trials? Error encountered?

Comment: Expected output:
非洲 AFRICA

[1.]["Burundi","蒲隆地 / 布隆迪","11,178,921"]

[2.]["Djibouti","吉布地 / 吉布提","887,861"]

[3.]["Comoros","葛摩 / 科摩羅","788,474"]

Comment: ranked of country population put the numbers in descending order.

Answer (score 1):

Data collected inside `data_a` and `data_b`. The further data manipulation i'm leaving to you.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()) + "/chromedriver")
link = 'https://www.ifreesite.com/population/'
browser.get(link)

table = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="if_mainboxb"]/div[2]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/table')
data_rows = table.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')

data_a = []
data_b = []
for element in data_rows:

    # collect continent names
    continents = [name.text for name in element.find_elements_by_class_name('taggllj')]
    if len(continents) > 0:
        data_a.append(continents[0])
        data_b.append(continents[1])

    # collect population data
    population_data = element.text.splitlines()
    if len(population_data) == 4:
        data_a.append(population_data[0])
        data_b.append(population_data[2])
```

**Output:**

```
['非洲', 'Burundi | 11,178,921', 'Djibouti | 887,861', 'Ethiopia | 99,390,750', 'Madagascar | 24,235,390', 'Mauritius | 1,273,212', 'Mozambique | 27,977,863', .....]
```

Comment: I want ranked of country population put the numbers in descending order.
How can i do.
Thanks.

Comment: @user13043463 do this by you self. Majority of work is done, the rest is simple.

Comment: ok. Thank you give me  the further data manipulation information.
Cheers.